# Variable time between cron jobs (or similar implementation)

Tags: python-2.7, cron, cron-task

Here's the idea -- there's a website that I want to scrape. It updates every 10 minutes, but sometimes get's out of sync. It's important that the information I scrape is just before it updates. Each time I check the site, I can scrape the 'time remaining' until next update.

Is there a way to make a cron job that -- after each iteration -- I can specifically set the time to wait before running the the time (t+1) iteration based on some variable from the time (t) iteration?

I'm not particularly familiar with cron jobs -- my current super rough implementation just uses -sleep-. Not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and implementet basic checks in the program scraping the website.
I just let the crontab call the program and the program performs checks.
If the data was already in, the program just exits doing nothing.
It wastes a little processing resources but proved to be the most reliable solution.

Entry in crontab :

```
    */10 * * * * cd /var/www/vhosts/website/scripts && /usr/bin/python scraper.py
```

You can make the interval shorter to make fit the window of the updates on the site.

```
    */5 * * * * cd /var/www/vhosts/website/scripts && /usr/bin/python scraper.py
```

*/5 executes the script every 5 minutes, so you do not have to "sleep" the program.

I advise against manipulating a crontab with a program/script.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'at' command to set a new job for the next time you need to run it.

So if your scraper tells you the next update is in 7 minutes you can set the 'at' command to run 'now + 6 minutes'

Comment: Could you give me a bit more information? I can't find any documentation on just 'at.' Do you mean editing the crontab with the program script?